# Rename files depending on parent and grand-parent folder names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need windows batch file to prefix filename in subfolders with name of folder & subfolder name

e.g. I have folder created for date 12012017 with following structure

```
d:\12012017\1234\ABC\file1.txt
d:\12012017\1234\ABC\file2.txt
d:\12012017\5678\PQR\file3.txt
d:\12012017\2345\XYZ\file4.txt
```

Need them to rename to

```
d:\12012017\1234\ABC\1234_ABC_file1.txt
d:\12012017\1234\ABC\1234_ABC_file2.txt
d:\12012017\5678\PQR\5678_PQR_file3.txt
d:\12012017\2345\XYZ\2345_XYZ_file4.txt
```

Tried following code but didn't work

```
set mydate=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%
REM ECHO %mydate%
D:
CD D:\%mydate%
@ECHO STARTING RENAME
pushd D:\%mydate%
for /d %%D in (*) do (
@ECHO 1- pushd "%%D"
@ECHO CD  %%D
for /d %%X in (*) do (
@ECHO pushd "%%X"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
 @ECHO 2- pushd "%%F"
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
 @ECHO 3- pushd "%%P"
 @ECHO 4 - ren "%%F" "%%~nxD_%%~nxF"
    )
  )
)
  popd
)
popd
CD\
```

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41631463/edit)  and add what did you tried as code until now !

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/) And a question is a sentence terminated with a question mark `?`. "I need a script" is definitely not a question. Please read at least the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to get the current date in the correct format, but I will preserve your existing method that is locale dependent.

It is important to use FOR /F with DIR on the inner loop instead of simple FOR because simple FOR can iterate files that have been already named, but FOR /F will not.

```
@echo off

:: Set current directory to today's date
pushd "d:\%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%"

for /d %%A in (*) do (                    %= Iterate all child folders =%
  for /d %%B in ("%%A\*") do (            %= Iterate grandchild folders = %
    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (       %= Iterate result of DIR command =%
      'dir /b /a-d "%%~B\*" 2^>nul'       %= List all files in grandchild folder =%
    ) do ren "%%~B\%%F" "%%~A_%%~nxB_%%F" %= Rename each file =%
  )
)

popd
```

Comment: How is this working as a comment?
    %= Iterate all child folders =%

Comment: @Cornbeetle - Environment variable names cannot contain `=`, except for dynamic variables like `%=ExitCode%`. And even dynamic variables do not have any `=` in the name except for the first character. So `%= Anything =%` is guaranteed to expand to nothing as long as the content does not include `%` or `:`.

Comment: An empty variable used as a comment, I love it!